# Software to develop an app or web-app?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, game-development

-Since my question doesn't really pertain to anything specific, I really do not know where to post this question. If I've asked it on the wrong site or improperly, please direct me how to ask it so as to get the best answers, thanks!

Setup: I have recently taken a huge interest in coding and I have found it very enjoyable.  I started by playing around in Python, as it was recommended to be easy to learn.  I created several working GUI's of things that I would like to implement into my game project.  From there I began to wonder how I would make my game accessible to my friends.
I have my idea in place, I just don't know what steps need to be taken to execute it.

My idea is this: I would like to create a dashboard/web-app/app (whatever you wish to call it) which my D&D friends could connect to and we could all play.  I would like to create a database (I assume) which would hold each players data, and update it when changes are made, aswell as be able to have a live chat which we could talk in and perform dice rolls in (I have made a dice roller and equipment bonus calculator in python).  At this moment in time, I do not care about it being accessible to the world or publishing or anything like that, I simply wish for my friends to be able to connect in real time.

My questions then are the following:

- What would be the easiest way for a beginner to 
  even tackle such a project?
- What language should I focus on learning?
- Should I use something like React?
- Should I focus on learning Sqlite and Flask? Would it be able to do this?
- What would be the simplest way to look at this 
  type of application?

  - I would need a server and a database, aswell 
    as a client end correct?

Again: Apologies if this was asked in the wrong place, I am simply looking for GENERAL advice, nothing too specific about anything in particular. Thanks!

Comment: "`I would need a server and a database, aswell as a client end correct?` - correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client**

I would use JS (AngualrJS 1,x, but you might be better off with React I would use JS (AngualrJS 1,x, but you might be better off with React (or React Native, if you want to use smart phones, rather than desktop.

Or, if you do not yet know React, then consider Flutter? That aims to be cross Android/iOs/Windows/Mac/Linux

**Server**

Personally, I would use PHP. It powers over 90% of all servers, and I have 20 years experience.

If you are leaning everything from scratch, then maybe Node.Js? That way you only have to learn JS (if you go with React, not Flutter, though).

**Database**

Personally, I cut my teeth on RDBMS, and would choose MySqL, MaraiaDb or Sqlite.

Or, you could got he NoSql route & learn MogoDb, CouncDB, etc

At the end of the day, you will have to Goggle & see what suits you, but feel free to ask questions here

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  That gives me a more clear understanding of what I should look into.  That's exactly what I was looking for, I am learning from scratch and just want to see if i can make it work.  I suppose then Node.Js would the route maybe.